# True or false? "sum of an m-strongly convex and a convex function is m-strongly convex"

Tags: optimization, functions, convex-analysis

I would like to know if the following conjecture is true or false?

*If $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ where $g$ is m-strongly convex and $h$ is convex, then $f$ is m-strongly convex.*

NOTE: For a non-differentiable function $F$, m-strongly convexity 
means $F(y) \geq F(x) + g^T(y - x) + \frac{m}{2} ||y - x||^2, \forall x, y$ where $g \in \partial F(x)$ is a subgradient of $F$ at $x$. If $F$ is differentiable, m-strongly convexity can **also** be defined as $\nabla^2 F(x) \succeq m I, \forall x$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. You can see [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions), [this blog post](https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/2013/04/04/orf523-strong-convexity/) by Sébastien Bubeck, or [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4820/2014sp/notes/dscnt.pdf) from the Algorithms course at Cornell University for more details on strong convexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can just add the inequalities. That is, if $g$ is $m$-strongly convex then, for some $a \in \partial g(x)$
$$
g(y) \ge g(x) + a^T(y-x) + \frac{m}{2}\|y-x\|^2,
$$
And if $h$ is convex, then for some $b \in \partial h(x)$:
$$
h(y) \ge h(x) + b^T(y-x),
$$
Then by adding we have:
$$
g(y) +h(y) \ge g(x) +h(x) + (a+b)^T(y-x) + \frac{m}{2}\|y-x\|^2
$$
$$
f(y) \ge f(x) + (a+b)^T(y-x) + \frac{m}{2}\|y-x\|^2
$$
So $f$ is strongly $m$-convex and $a+b \in \partial f(x)$:

Comment: thank you for the proof! It all makes sense. I think to finish the proof we need to show that the conclusion holds for any $g \in \partial f$, and for that we can use the fact that $\partial f = \partial g + \partial h$ where $+$ is the sumset (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset) of the two subgradient sets.

Comment: The above argument shows that $\partial g + \partial h \subseteq \partial f$, which is all you need for this.